# ERROR: Class "test2" is mapped, but is not included in any

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, persistence

I'm getting the error "Class "test2" is mapped, but is not included in any" in eclipse, however the class is included in persistence xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="test1">
        <class>com.test.domains.test1</class>
        <properties>
                  <!-- properties for schema1 here -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    <persistence-unit name="test2">
        <class>com.test.test2</class>
        <properties>
                  <!-- properties for schema 2 here -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Why does this error appear. Do I have to configure it different for 2 db schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse (or more specifically Dali) do have limitation, it does not support two persistence units. That is also told in their [pages](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/gettingstarted.php):

> Currently Dali only supports one Persistence Unit and one Persistence
>   XML file per project. Other configurations can exist in a JPA project,
>   but the validation and defaults processing may not be correct when
>   multiple persistence units are used.

What it comes to JPA itself, persistence.xml seems to becorrect. There is no need to add same class to two persistence units.

Comment: OK, I can use one user who can access to both schema's. Then it will work with one persistence unit, thanks.

Comment: If interested there is more discussion on this topic here - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194833.